# Should I use a root namespace?

Tags: language-agnostic, packages, namespace

I'm currently working on a couple projects in Flash ActionScript, and I've been building up a small library of classes. I've been using a naming convention similar to:

`foo.events.Bar` and `foo.controls.Baz`, but I've noticed that many people have released their libraries in the `com` and `org` package/namespace (i.e. `com.foo.events.Bar` and `com.foo.controls.Baz`). I assume the meaning of `com` is `common` or `community`, and that `org` is `organization`.

Is there a particular reason to adding an *additional* namespace?

Is this common for namespaced languages (Java, C#, AS3,...)?

Comment: This convention (`com...`, `org...`) seems more popular with Java, I don't seem to recall seeing it as much with C++ or C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**com** doesn't mean common or community, it means *commerical*, [same as in the web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com).  This is important, as the meaning defines the conventions, if you wish to follow them.

As the naming specifications that [@Dean](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66048#66052) referred to say, packages are a **hierarchical naming pattern**, which means that the most general distinction comes first.

For that, you should follow convention, which is:

- If you are building **commercial software** use **com** (`.yourcompanyname`).
- If you are building **[free/open source software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software)**, use **org** (`.yourorganizationname`).

---

*As a side note, I remember reading somewhere, though I can't find the source, that [Tim Berners-Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) (creator of the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)) said, if he were to create the specification over again, he would put the [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (`.com`, `.org` etc.) first (mirroring software package conventions), as it is the highest level of the hierarchy.*

Comment: I'd read that bit TLD + Tim Berners-Lee before as well. I didn't realize it was to mirror software package conventions (or I'd forgotten :-D).

Comment: @zzzzBov - I don't know if it is *to* mirror them, or if he simply believes that to be the right way, and that software packages got it right.

Comment: either way it would have made more sense with increased specificity the farther right you go. It would simplify many issues with sub-domains, as you could easily pattern-match the root `com.foo.bar/baz` vs `bar.foo.com/baz`

Answer (score 2):

The first place I ever saw that naming convention was Java, where is was encouraged that [you prefix your package names with your backwards domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions). So if you own "www.foo.com" then you would name your packages "com.foo.whatever" (leave off the "www").

This avoids the possibility of package name conflicts (for example if company "foo" in Australia releases a package, it would be "au.com.foo.whatever").

I've seen it used in other languages as well (python springs to mind) but I believe they just borrowed it from Java.

Answer (score 1):

*Should* is an interesting term, but in any case the concept behind name-spaces is to avoid clashing.

In the days of **C** and other languages like it :-) , you had functions.  If two libraries provided the same function name, you could be out of luck at either compile or link time.

Library one:

```
/* code dealing with gui */
int draw(void*);
```

Library two:

```
/* code dealing with printer */
int draw(void*);
```

So we started to get in the habit of adding a little company/library based prefix

Library Other one:

```
/* code dealing with GUI */
int GUI_draw(void*);
```

Library Other two:

```
/* other print code */
int PRINT_draw(void*);
```

And this helped quite a bit, more typing, but since you were less likely to use two of the same library in the same application, it did pretty well.

Languages evolved and the concept became more refined to be a first class concept of namespaces.

Java (citation needed) may have been the first to (widely) adopt the reversed domain name as a namespace.  By the very nature of the DNS system, this ensured that there would be no clashing of same names.

So back to *should*; if you are coding for your personal use, then likely don't bother worrying about it.

If you are coding for a company, consider using their name in the standard reverse order.  If the code does not go anywhere else (i.e. is not released open-source), it will not make much of a difference, but it will be least surprise item for future developers who come along and expect that *standard* convention.